# UIBarButtonItem is not showing up

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

This is a really weird problem I just encountered. I have a ViewController (lets call it `ConfirmationViewController`) in a Storyboard with a "Done" button which is a `UIBarButtonItem`. I am instantiating and pushing this `ConfirmationViewController` on the navigation stack from two different places, each time pushing it from another ViewController (lets call it `EventViewController`).

In one of cases, this UIBarButton appears, but in the other one, it doesn't. Even the navigation bar title doesn't appear. Also, the back button appears only as an arrow, without the text. Everything else on the `ConfirmationViewController` is exactly the same. It also gets pushed on the navigation stack in exactly the same way, by the `EventViewController`.

I even tried adding a UIBarButtonItem using code instead of an IBOutlet from the Storyboard. In this case too, it only shows up in one scenario and doesn't show up in the other scenario.

Any idea what is going on?